# Regex to remove <script> and its content in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove scripts and their content from html body and this is what I have came up until now

```
just_text = just_text.replace(/<\s*script[^>]*>(<\s*\/script[^>]*>|$)/ig, '');
```

It does not work as want to, I still get the content.

Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Did you consider using an HTML parser for this task instead of regular expressions? They're not well-suited to process HTML.

Comment: *"remove scripts and their content from html body"* Does this mean you are modifying the actual page and are not only having an HTML string?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yeap I need an regexp

Comment: @MariosTasos: Why? Why wouldn't a parser do the job?

Comment: @FelixKling I am only storing string content I am removing any tags

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am already using Cheeriojs to get the body I dont need another library I need a regex for performance issues

Comment: @Marios: HTML parsing and DOM manipulation capabilities are built into the browser, because that's what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to such questions is always the same: Don't use regular expressions. Instead, parse the HTML, modify the DOM and serialize it back to HTML if you need to.

Example:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = just_text;

// find and remove `script` elements
var scripts = container.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = scripts.length; i--; ) {
    scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
}

just_text = container.innerHTML;
```

If you want to remove the `script` tags from the page itself, it's basically the same:

```
var scripts = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = scripts.length; i--; ) {
    scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Correct answer, but I'm not sure I like `i--` as a loop condition... Why not simply `while(scripts.length) scripts[0].parentNode` etc?

Comment: @thg435: I had that first. Then I remembered that accessing `.length` reevaluates the `NodeList` (updates it) and I wanted to avoid that. So iterating over list in reverse order seemed to make the most sense (doesn't have to be with this loop setup, I just like it as shorthand). On the other hand, maybe accessing an element of the list (`scripts[i]`) reevaluates it as well and there is nothing gained through that anyway ;)

Comment: @FelixKling useful answer but I needed a regex in that case big thank you though will certainly use this approach next time